# Consegui pesquisar mais 1 query no banco de dados com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer uma pesquisa no meu código, buscando outros campos, por exemplo, procurar pessoas que foram cadastradas com o nome da mãe " fulano de tal", mas não estou conseguindo bater uma lógica... só consigo pesquisar 1 campo, que é o nome.

```
 <?php
            if(isset($_POST['nome'])) {
            $pesquisar = $_POST['nome'] ;
           
            $result_msg_contatos = "SELECT * FROM cadastro WHERE nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%' LIMIT 30";

            $resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($conn , $result_msg_contatos);
   
            
         } else {
            //Verificar se esta sendo passado na URL a página atual, senão é atribuido a pagina
            $pagina=(isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
            
            //Selecionar todos os itens da tabela 
            $result_msg_contato = "SELECT * FROM cadastro";
            $resultado_msg_contato = mysqli_query($conn , $result_msg_contato);
            
            //Contar o total de itens
            $total_msg_contatos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_msg_contato);
            
            //Seta a quantidade de itens por página
            $quantidade_pg = 20;
            
            //calcular o número de páginas 
            $num_pagina = ceil($total_msg_contatos/$quantidade_pg);
            
            //calcular o inicio da visualizao   
            $inicio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;
            
            //Selecionar  os itens da página
            $result_msg_contatos = "SELECT * FROM cadastro limit $inicio, $quantidade_pg";
            $resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($conn , $result_msg_contatos);
            $total_msg_contatos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_msg_contatos);
         }



<form method="POST" action="gerar_planilha_especifica.php">
            <div class="row espaco">
               <div class="pull-right">                 
                  <a href="../../index.php"><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success'>Cadastrar</button></a>
                  <a href="gerar_planilha.php"><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Gerar Excel</button></a>
                  <input type="submit" value="Excel Especifico" class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <table class="table">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th class="text-center">Id</th>
                           <th class="text-center">Nome </th>
                           <th class="text-center">Nome da mãe</th>
                           <th class="text-center">Nome do Pai</th>
                           <th class="text-center">cpf</th>
                           <th class="text-center">rg</th>
                           <th class="text-center">email</th>
                           <th class="text-center">Data Nasc</th>
                           <th class="text-center">telefone</th>
                           <th class="text-center">Whatsapp</th>
                           <th class="text-center">rua</th>
                           <th class="text-center">numero</th>
                           <th class="text-center">bairro</th>
                           <th class="text-center">cidade</th>
                           <th class="text-center">estado</th>
                           <th class="text-center">indicacao</th>
                           <th class="text-center">cep</th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <?php while($row_msg_contatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_msg_contatos)){?>
                        <tr>
                           <?php $id = $row_msg_contatos["id"]; ?>
                           <td class="text-center">
                              <?php echo "<input type='radio' name='msg_contato[$id]' value='1'" ?>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["id"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["nome"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["mae"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["pai"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["cpf"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["rg"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["email"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["dtnasc"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["telefone"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["zap"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["rua"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["numero"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["bairro"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["cidade"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["estado"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["indicacao"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"><?php echo $row_msg_contatos["cep"]; ?></td>
                           <td class="text-center"> 
                              <?php echo
                                 "<a href='proc_apagar_usuario.php?id=" . $row_msg_contatos['id'] . "'>Apagar</a><br><hr>";
                                 ?>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
            </div>
      </form>
```

Eu fiz isso após a resposta de @ademir-mazer-jr-nuno, e continuo sem consegui filtrar :/

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cadastro";
$where = "";

if(isset($_POST['nome'])) {
     $pesquisar = $_POST['nome'] ;
        
     $where .= " nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['mae'])) {
     $pesquisar = $_POST['mae'] ;           

     // esta linha testa se a variável where já tem conteúdo, se sim adiciona o 
     // AND caso não inicia ela vazia
     $where = isempty($where) ? "" : $where . " AND ";
     $sql .= " mae LIKE '%$pesquisar%'";
}

if(isset($_POST['cidade'])) {
     $pesquisar = $_POST['cidade'] ;           

     // esta linha testa se a variável where já tem conteúdo, se sim adiciona o 
     // AND caso não inicia ela vazia
     $where = isempty($where) ? "" : $where . " AND ";
     $sql .= " cidade LIKE '%$pesquisar%'";




    // finaliza a construção da query, se where for vazio somente limita o resultado
   // caso contrário adiciona a cláusula
   $sql .= empty($where) ? "" : " WHERE " . $where;
   $sql .= " LIMIT 30 ";
     
}else{

//Verificar se esta sendo passado na URL a página atual, senão é atribuido a pagina
$pagina=(isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
                
//Selecionar todos os itens da tabela 
$result_msg_contato = "SELECT * FROM cadastro";
$resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($conn , $result_msg_contato);

//Contar o total de itens
$total_msg_contatos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_msg_contatos);

//Seta a quantidade de itens por página
$quantidade_pg = 20;

//calcular o número de páginas 
$num_pagina = ceil($total_msg_contatos/$quantidade_pg);

//calcular o inicio da visualizao   
$inicio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

//Selecionar  os itens da página
$result_msg_contatos = "SELECT * FROM cadastro limit $inicio, $quantidade_pg";
$resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($conn , $result_msg_contatos);
$total_msg_contatos = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_msg_contatos);

       }
          
                    ?>
```

Comment: Sua lógica no else te leva a sempre entrar nela se não tem uma cidade no parâmetro. Você entende como funciona o If Else ???

Answer (score -1):

Você está testando se existe um parâmetro de post para nome, caso  exista, ele somente monta a query para este campo. Caso não exista você monta o que me parece um retorno copmpleto para todos os registros paginados da tabela.

Uma possível solução seria montar a base da query, e então testar cada um dos parâmetros possíveis como filtros e ir concatenando na query.

No exemplo a seguir estou considerando apenas 3 parâmetros e alterando apenas a parte PHP colocada na pergunta relacionada à filtrar com critérios, para que você entenda a lógica da solução e complemente em seu contexto, note também que não conheço seu banco de dados então os nomes de campos são sugestões.

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM cadastro";
   $where = "";

   if(isset($_POST['nome'])) {
        $pesquisar = $_POST['nome'] ;
           
        $where .= "nome LIKE '%$pesquisar%'";
   }

   if(isset($_POST['nome_mae'])) {
        $pesquisar = $_POST['nome_mae'] ;           

        // esta linha testa se a variável where já tem conteúdo, se sim adiciona o 
        // AND caso não inicia ela vazia
        $where = empty($where) ? "" : $where . " AND ";
        $sql .= "nome_mae LIKE '%$pesquisar%'";
   }

   if(isset($_POST['cidade'])) {
        $pesquisar = $_POST['cidade'] ;           

        // esta linha testa se a variável where já tem conteúdo, se sim adiciona o 
        // AND caso não inicia ela vazia
        $where = empty($where) ? "" : $where . " AND ";
        $sql .= "cidade LIKE '%$pesquisar%'";
   }

   // finaliza a construção da query, se where for vazio somente limita o resultado
   // caso contrário adiciona a cláusula
  $sql .= empty($where) ? "" : " WHERE " . $where;
  $sql .= " LIMIT 30";


   $resultado_msg_contatos = mysqli_query($conn , $result_msg_contatos);
```

Se não conhece o operador ternário que usei nos testes da variável `$where` [dê uma olhada na documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).